# PHP hash function

Tags: php

Recently I started to make an UCP for a game server but I come to a problem. The game server hash passwords with sha256 and salt. The hashed password look like this `399B77A0AD470496AE09579C2CA3FAF2F01E8A63D9F4ECFA6F60E32CE2E7E5E9`
but the php hash function for sha256 give this hash `399b77a0ad470496ae09579c2ca3faf2f01e8a63d9f4ecfa6f60e32ce2e7e5e9`.

When the user input and the password from database it's compared, they are not the same and user can't login.

How to ignore uppercase/lowercase or how to make the hash function to hash the input in uppercase?

Comment: Are you doing the comparison on a database level or PHP level?

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

`strtoupper($your-lower-case-hash)`

Comment: Thank you, i try to learn php with this little job

Comment: Great! Php is awesome. Just ask if you need some more help :)

Comment: Accept his answer

Answer (score 0):

Another option to Matias solution would be

```
if (0 === strcasecmp($phpHash, $mysqlHash)) {}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php